# Как скопировать в базу данных содержание тега

Tags: php, html, mysql

Нужно скопировать из тега div с классом "text_block" всё содержимое изнутри и занести в БД MYSQL используя php.

```
<div class="other"/><div class="text_block"/>html код</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это кусок html находится на вашей странице, и эго нужно оттуда отправить на сервер, то так:

```
main.php:
    <?php
        @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        @mysql_select_db("DataBaseName");
        if(isset($_GET["innethtml"]))
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `TableName` (`name`) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["innethtml"]) . "')")
    ?>

index.html:
        <html>
            ...
            <script type="text/javascript">
                  function send(){
                      var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
                      x.open("GET", "main.php?innethtml=" + document.getElementsByClassName("text_block")[0].innerHTML, true);
                      x.send(null);
                  }
            </script>
            </body>
                ...
                <div class="other"/><div class="text_block"/>html код</div></div>
                ...
                <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="send()"/>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Для того, что бы не было нехорошестей из-за того, что несколько классов `text_block`, надо задать идинтификатор и по нему делать, или проверять родителя этого элемента.

Comment: не совсем то что мне нужно, но зато понял суть.

Answer (score 0):

Вытащить с помощью jQuery или банальным innerHTML (innerText) и отправить на сервер php-скрипту, который отправит это в БД